# Accessing Spring Boot resource as File in Controller

Tags: spring-boot

I need to access the files I have in /src/main/resources/static/myfolder in my Spring Boot Controller using the java.io.File API. I tried

```
File folder = new File("/myfolder/");
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have time to check it out, but you might look at using the Spring `ResourceLoader` available in the boot application context... I would think it would have access to the static folder contents, though not sure what the path would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/static/myfolder").getFile());
File[] files = file.listFiles();
```